# How to get record counts using EF

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to write a query in EF to get the record count.

```
var count = await _context.Programs.Where(a=>a.StudentId == request.Id)
                   .Where(b => b.Phase == 'Started').CountAsync();
```

However, its giving below error. I have Phase defined as string

Too many characters in character literal [netreact]csharp(CS1012)

Also, how to I extend the query for 'Started' or 'Hold' [Phase in ('Started','Hold')]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend to Hold and Started

```
var count = await _context.Programs.Where(a=>a.StudentId == request.Id)
                   .Where(b => b.Phase == "Started" || b.Phase == "Hold").CountAsync();
```

Quoted from answer by Mohamed Adel, you can also combine both query in a single query like this

```
var count = await _context.Programs.Where(a=>a.StudentId == request.Id &&( a.Phase == "Started" || a.Phase == "Hold")).CountAsync();
```

Or better

```
var count = await _context.Programs.CountAsync(a=>a.StudentId == request.Id &&(a.Phase == "Started" || a.Phase == "Hold"));
```

Comment: thank you. Learning new EF ways everyday

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes ' ' for char of 1 character example 'z' or 'a'

Use double quotes " " for string of many characters example "test"

So Please change it to be as below

```
var count = await _context.Programs.Where(a=>a.StudentId == request.Id)
                   .Where(b => b.Phase == "Started").CountAsync();
```

Also you can combine your conditions like below

```
var count = await _context.Programs.Where(a=>a.StudentId == request.Id && a.Phase == "Started" ).CountAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please suggest how to use "Started" or "Hold" also?